# How to sort products whithout prices (zero price) to bottom of category list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I wrote a WooCommerce function but that doesn’t work properly.

Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'the_posts', 'move_zero_price_products_to_end', 20, 2 );

function move_zero_price_products_to_end( $posts, $query ) {
  if ( ! is_admin() && ( is_shop() || is_product_category() ) ) {
    $posts_with_price = array();
    $posts_without_price = array();
    
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
      $price = (float) get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_price', true );
      if ( $price <= 0 ) {
        $posts_without_price[] = $post;
      } else {
        $posts_with_price[] = $post;
      }
    }
    
    $posts = array_merge( $posts_with_price, $posts_without_price );
  }
  
  return $posts;
}
```

but not work correct if I have too many products and for example I have category in my shop with 9 pages

In this case, in each of the pages separately among the products of the same page, those with prices are displayed first and those without price or with zero price are displayed at the end.

But in general, I want to sort all the products that have a price first, and then the products that have no price (they have no price - their price is zero) are displayed at the end right after products with prices.

Can you edit and improve this code for me and solve my problem?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with each kind of price (`var_export($posts);`) and show us your exact desired result.  If this isn't a duplicate question, it should be very easy to answer.  Why is `$query`  passed in if you don't ever access its data?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'lowprice_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');

function lowprice_woocommerce_catalog_orderby($args) {
    if (is_shop() || is_product_category()) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '_price';
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: this code doesn't work. and I do not need sort by price, I need in default WordPress sorting option without any change just one change sort (move) all product without price (or with zero price) to bottom of the list (end of each category)

Comment: In that case, excluding the products without price from the main query and later add the products without price into the array maybe the work aorund